# Bash keyboard shortcuts that use Alt do not work on a Mac

Tags: macos, bash

According to [this Bash syntax tutorial](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-keyboard.html), I should be able to move left one word if I hit `alt b`. On a Mac, the Option key is the Alt key (or at least it's supposed to be). But when I press `option b` I get this symbol instead of moving back:

```
∫∫∫∫∫∫∫
```

If I try `shift option b`, I get this:

```
ııııııııı
```

None of the Bash shortcuts using Alt are available to me when I try to use them with Option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Default OS X Terminal emulator? Then ‘Settings’ → ‘Keyboard’ → “Use option as meta key”.

Comment: These days, this setting is a separate menu item called "Use Option as Meta Key" that lives in the Edit menu.

Answer (score 3):

As [the bash manual page describes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html):

> On  keyboards  without a meta key, M-x means ESC x, i.e., press the Escape key then the x key. This makes ESC the meta prefix.
>
> [...]
>
> forward-char (C-f) Move forward a character.
>
> backward-char (C-b) Move back a character.
>
> forward-word (M-f) Move forward to the end of the next word.  Words are composed of alphanumeric characters (letters and digits).
>
> backward-word (M-b) Move  back  to  the start of the current or previous word.  Words are composed of alphanumeric characters (letters and digits).

So indeed, Esc *followed* by B moves back one word, and holding down Ctrl *while* pressing B moves back one character. (So, you might like [Dmitry's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/805223/option-not-alt-on-a-mac/805247#805247) better, or to move around words just hold down Option while pressing the left or right cursor key.)

As an aside, as for *"On a mac, the option key is the alt key (or at least it's supposed to be)"*: OS X doesn't use any Alt key. The only reason that label is printed on that key, is to help you when you're using a Mac with some other operating system.